# python tkinter frame widget background color is not showing

Tags: python, tkinter, background, frame

I have shared all my code snippet. But I think unnecessary/ so I had to delete most unrelated parts

I created tkinter GUI. The functionality works fine, but problem is as you will discover backgorund colors of frame widget does not show.

And I wonder why?

I guess, it is due to I did not write width and height of frame widget.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd


# Create object
root = Tk()

# Adjust size
root.geometry( "600x200" )

#create frames
frame1=Frame(root,bg='white')
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0)

frame1_2=Frame(root,bg='red')
frame1_2.grid(row=1,column=0)

frame1_3=Frame(root,bg='yellow')
frame1_3.grid(row=2,column=0)

frame2=Frame(root,bg='blue')
frame2.grid(row=0,column=1)

# Dropdown menu options
options = ls_categories
options2 = ls_country

# datatype of menu text
clicked = StringVar()
clickedCountry = StringVar()

# initial menu text
clicked.set( " None " )
clickedCountry.set( " None " )

# Create Dropdown menu
drop = OptionMenu( frame1 , clicked , *options )
drop.grid(row=0,column=0)
dropCountry = OptionMenu( frame1 , clickedCountry , *options2 )
dropCountry.grid(row=0,column=2)

# Create button, it will change label text
button = Button( frame1 ,width=13, text = "select" , command = show,padx=3,pady=3 ).grid(row=2,column=0)
btnChCat = Button( frame1 ,width=13, text = "choose Category" , command = choose,padx=3,pady=3 ).grid(row=1,column=0)
btnChCountry = Button( frame1 ,width=13, text = "choose Country" , command = chooseCountry,padx=3,pady=3  ).grid(row=1,column=2)
bntSubmit=Button(frame1_2,width=13,text="Search", command=f_submit,padx=3,pady=3 ).grid(row=0,column=0)
bntLinks=Button(frame1_3,width=13,text="GetWebLinks", command=a_links,padx=3,pady=3 ).grid(row=0,column=0)

# Create Label
label = Label( frame1 , text = " " )
label.grid(row=1,column=1)
label2 = Label( frame2 , text = " " )
label2.grid(row=4,column=0)

# Execute tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code won't run, it's missing the definition of some important variables

Comment: `I guess, it is due to I did not write width and height of frame widget.` - That does appear to be part of the issue

Comment: frames by default shrink to fit their children. Add `padx` and `pady` values when adding widgets to frames and you can visualize the frames.

Comment: I added unfortunately padx nor pady let me see `frame1_3=Frame(root,bg='green')` green background color

Comment: @xlmaster: I saw it when I added padding when adding `btnLinks` to that frame. `bntLinks=Button(frame1_3,width=13,text="GetWebLinks", ).grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=10)`

Comment: I edited the code you to see, where I added padx and pady. But with no effect

Comment: wow. Thanks @BryanOakley, I did not know to add grid() method. Iadded wrongly to Button() class. After your comment. Idid so. And now works